# Create thumbnail images after using the CakePHP 2 upload plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, image-processing, thumbnails, cakephp-2.x

I am using the CakePHP Upload [plugin](https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload) since quite some time and I am really happy with it:

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'Upload.Upload' => array(
        'image' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'dir' => 'dir'
            ),
            'thumbnailSizes' => array(
                'xvga' => '1024x768',
                'vga' => '640x480',
                'thumb' => '300x300'
            ),
            'thumbnailMethod'  => 'php',
        )
    )
);
```

In a new usecase I have to make some better thumbnails than some static downgrade of the resolution to 640x640 or 300x300. I want to have a resolution per image orientation or the ability to say that an image should not exceed 30kB.

Jose Gonzales, the plugin author, makes it clear that the Upload plugin does not create thumbnails:

*This plugin does not create thumbnails. You can use a custom Transformer to create modified versions of file uploads.*

I'd like to know how this could be achieved together with the existing Upload plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was using **glide** from **thephpleague**: 
https://github.com/thephpleague/glide

As described on the documents page, it allows for "on-the-fly" image manipulation such as:

- Adjust, resize and add effects to images using a simple HTTP based API.
- Manipulated images are automatically cached and served with
  far-future expires headers.
- Change orientation
- Add watermarks
- Add filters
- Add borders
- Define max size of image

The implementation is as simple as this in CakePHP (no plugin needed). Add the library as dependency in your composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "league/glide" : "1.0.x"
},
```

run `./composer.phar update`

In the controller action it can be called like this:

```
public function imageResize() {
    $server = League\Glide\ServerFactory::create([
        'source' => 'files',
        'cache' => 'files/cache',
        'watermarks' => 'files/watermarks'
    ]);

    $server->outputImage($path, $_GET);
}
```

So I can simply call the image from the app like this:

```
https://www.url.com/images/imageResize?w=480&mark=mark.png&markpos=right&markh=60&markpad=4
```

---

Another useful library is **Adaptive Images**: http://adaptive-images.com

It detects your visitor's screen size and automatically creates, caches, and delivers device appropriate re-scaled versions of your web page's embeded HTML images. No mark-up changes needed. It is intended for use with Responsive Designs and to be combined with Fluid Image techniques.

Answer (score 1):

> In a new usecase I have to make some better thumbnails than some static downgrade of the resolution to 640x640 or 300x300

What prevents you from doing your custom image manipulations after the plugin processed the upload? You could extend the behavior as well and add what you want.

You can use my [Imagine plugin](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-imagine-plugin) that comes with a behavior for easy image processing. Or combine it with [FileStorage](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage) which uses Imagine to automatically process images after upload.

Or use [the underlying library Imagine](https://imagine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#) directly.

> I want to have a resolution per image orientation or the ability to say that an image should not exceed 30kB.

Use validation rules for that.

Comment: That plugin looks nice but unfortunately it is for CakePHP 3.

Comment: Read more than just the title? There is a **bold** line with a link to the migration from 2 to 3. Or use Imagine directly. So check the branches / tags. https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-imagine-plugin/tree/1.x